# css and js files are not loaded with multiple .htaccess slimframework

Tags: slim

well i have setup slim skeleton directly in public_html where in that directory their is first .htaccess file contain routing to public folder.
first .htaccess contain:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /public/
RewriteRule ^$ public/
```

due to which my domain is directly pointing to public/index.php
which contain second .htaccess file with slimframework standard .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Some hosts may require you to use the `RewriteBase` directive.
# If you need to use the `RewriteBase` directive, it should be the
# absolute physical path to the directory that contains this htaccess file.
#
# RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

Because of this my css and js files are not loaded inside template and they are going as in console

> GET http://domain.com/css/bootstrap.min.css 
>   returning 404 error
>   I am struugling with this issue from two days but still not able to get where should i change as its working fine on my local server but not over godaddy server.

Comment: Can you just set your web root for your domain to `public_html/public/`?

Comment: i wish if that was possible. Then life become more easier actually its over godaddy shared hosting.

Comment: Save yourself lots of headaches and invest in proper hosting which allows you to set the document root.

Comment: Will but is their can be a solution. Now